# Average Hamming distance between strings after some number of random substitutions in a population of initially identical elements

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Let's say I have a set $S$, $(s_1, ..., s_i, ..., s_P) \in S$, of $P$ identical strings over a $k$-letter alphabet, each of length $|s_i| = L$.  With uniform random probability across all strings in $S$ (and all string positions in any $s_i$), I randomly substitute one character for another.  And I do so $N$ times.

For $N >> 1$, all $s_i$ will approximate random sequences.  But what is the average Hamming distance between any two strings as a function of $N$?

Comment: For each character change, the average distance (for small N) goes up by 2/P with high probability.  When N gets to be a significant fraction of LP, then the average distance probably increases with some form of exponential decay, again with high probability.  For how big an N do you need to know this?  Also with what confidence level?  Gerhard "Probably Sure It's Mostly Correct" Paseman, 2011.05.24

Comment: Gerhard, thanks for your comment!  I'm interested in $N$ up to the point where the average Hamming distance between any two sequences is, on average, 0.5*L to 0.1*L.  

Comment: A qualitative understanding of what a plot of Average Hamming Distance vs. "N" looks like is really what I'm after.  I'm not really hopeful that anyone will be able to provide an explicit function... 

Comment: You can plot the results provided by Prof. Israel.  I believe they will reflect my remarks above.  If you do some simulations of your model (which is but slightly different from what is answered), I will be surprised if you see any qualititative difference for k > 2.
Even for k=2 I suspect the simulations will resemble the formula's prediction, so Prof Israel's answer will still give you the qualitative understanding you mention.  Gerhard "Mostly Sure It's Probably Correct" Paseman, 2011.05.25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At each move, I assume you choose one of the character positions in one of the strings (with equal probabilities for all), and replace the character in that position by a randomly chosen character (with equal probabilities for all - note that this allows the possibility that the new character is the same as the old one).
Let $X(n)$ be the event that after $n$ moves, the $i$'th character in string $j_1$ is the same as the $i$'th character in string $j_2$.  Now if in move $n$ the position chosen was anything other than the $i$'th character in string $j_1$ or $j_2$, $X(n) = X(n-1)$, while if it was either of those, $X(n)$ has probability $1/k$.  Thus ${\rm P}(X(n)) = (1 - \frac{2}{PL}) {\rm P}(X(n-1)) + \frac{2}{PLk}$ with ${\rm P}(X(0)) = 1$.  The solution of this recurrence is
${\rm P}(X(n)) = \frac{1}{k} + \frac{k-1}{k} \left( 1-\frac{2}{PL} \right)^n$.
The expected Hamming distance between strings $j_1$ and $j_2$ after $n$ moves is
$L (1 - {\rm P}(X(n)))$.

(added in response to unknown(yahoo)'s further question): if the new character must be different from the existing one at that position, the recurrence becomes ${\rm P}(X(n)) =  (1 - \frac{2}{PL}) {\rm P}(X(n-1)) + \frac{2}{PL} \frac{1-P(X(n-1))}{k-1}$, and the solution is ${\rm P}(X(n)) = \frac{1}{k} + \frac{k-1}{k} \left(1 - \frac{2k}{PL(k-1)}\right)^n$.  Again the expected Hamming distance after $n$ moves is $L (1 - {\rm P}(X(n)))$.

Comment: ...and once again I underestimate the people here. =)

Comment: @Robert Israel, pressing my luck, "with equal probabilities for all - note that this allows the possibility that the new character is the same as the old one", what if we enforce a rule that a particular substitution must not reselect the character that exists are the randomly selected string position?

Comment: Another way to get this is that the strings are identical in a position if neither has been altered there, which happens with probability $p = (1-2/(PL))^n$, or if at least one has been altered and you got lucky, probability $(1-p)/k$, total $p+(1-p)/k$. The average Hamming distance can be computed from these linearly.